# How to determine if mongoDB directoryperdb is set?

Tags: c++, mongodb

Our application using the C++ mongoDB driver requires the configuration file option directoryperdb to be true. How do I test if the current mondod instance has this set to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) From mongo shell run, db.serverCmdLineOpts() // check for directoryperdb

2) Go to the mongodb storage directory, and check if each database is having a folder or not ( admin folder, local folder, or any other database folder that you created )

Answer (score 0):

And in C++

```
mongo::BSONObj options;
client_connection.runCommand("admin",BSON ( "getCmdLineOpts" << 1), options);
bool directoryperdb = options["parsed"]["directoryperdb"].boolean();
```